# Contact entity - where are the parent data stored when you set a 'contact' as parent customer?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I would like to link contacts between each others, in a way that a contact will be related to another contact as a Parent/Child relationship (migration process to get a tree view).

I saw into the contact entity metadata a parentcontactid column with a lookup type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328530.aspx

Their is no existing lookup field to add to contact forms.

So, I tested through the front-end to set the parentcustomerid to other contacts, you see the modifications on contacts pages, but when navigating into SQL management studio, I don't see entries for the parentcustomerid changed, always related to the Account anyway.

Could someone explain me what is the purpose of the "parentcontactid" if it is not possible to populate it or a way to do it?

Thanks

P.S.: wanted first to use connection entity to link my contacts, but my ETL software seems not have rights to make connections, so, I'm looking for an over way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `parentcustomerid` only. As far as I know `parentcontactid` was used by previous version of Dynamics CRM and now is deprecated and not available.

`parentcustomerid` is a special lookup type inside CRM called `Customer`, the field can accept `Account` or `Contact` values, so you need to build your Parent/Child relationship using this field.

Comment: I too am constantly struggling with "as far as I know" scenarios...maybe someday MS will give developers complete info on changes they make...

Comment: @keerz I started to work with CRM 4.0, but looks like this `parentcontactid` was used at least in CRM 1.0/CRM 1.2, probably kept from upgrade compatibility.

Comment: @everybody - I don't see where is stored the ID of the contact when I set as "parentcustomerid' a contact anyway. It sill keeps the GUID from the account into the contact table.
Into MSCRM I can see that the contact has for parent another contact, but where is stored this GUID contact?

Comment: parentcustomerid is an entityreference, so you need to cast first and after get the Id property

Comment: @Sébastien entityreference is a class to manage lookup content (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entityreference.aspx) and `cast` is type conversion (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion), again, you need to check if your ETL can manage this kind of fields